# Set the browser language in moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

By using `moment.js` I need to set the date language.
`moment.lang('fr');` or `moment.lang('en');` works fine.

I would like to set it based on language preference of the desktop/browser.
How can I get this variable in javascript?

P.S.

navigator.language.slice(0,2) works fine with the english language, but I am looking for a better solution

I am using jquery.

Comment: Are you implying that `navigator.language` isn't reliable?

Comment: In what way does the solution have to be better than navigator.language?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, for example, Internet Explorer maybe it does not support `navigator.language` and `slice`

Answer (score 0):

This should be cross-browser:

```
var lang = ( navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage ).slice( 0, 2 );
```

On my machine, I get `"en"` in Firefox, Chrome, and IE.